# R write table last longer for 2 columns than for whole dataframe

Tags: r

A dataframe with 40 columns:

This is executed after a few seconds

```
write.table(data_2[1:10000,], file = "/Volumes/2018/06_abteilungen/bi/analytics/tools/adobe/adobe_analytics/adobe_analytics_api_rohdaten/api_via_data_feed_auf_ftp/beispiel_datenexporte_data_feed/r_exporte/channel_va_closer.csv", sep = ";", col.names = NA)
```

This never ends:

```
write.table(data_2[1:1000,c(data_2$va_closer_detail,data_2$va_closer_id)], file = "/Volumes/2018/06_abteilungen/bi/analytics/tools/adobe/adobe_analytics/adobe_analytics_api_rohdaten/api_via_data_feed_auf_ftp/beispiel_datenexporte_data_feed/r_exporte/channel_va_closer.csv", sep = ";", col.names = NA)
```

How can I extract only 2 columns without performance-delay?

Comment: try using `data.table::fwrite`

Comment: You are using incorrect subset syntax... answer coming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[` to subset a data frame either by giving it row/column indices or row/column names. For example:

```
dd = data.frame(col1 = rep(1:2, 5), col2 = c(rep(1:3, 3), 1), col3 = 'a')
dd
#    col1 col2 col3
# 1     1    1    a
# 2     2    2    a
# 3     1    3    a
# 4     2    1    a
# 5     1    2    a
# 6     2    3    a
# 7     1    1    a
# 8     2    2    a
# 9     1    3    a
# 10    2    1    a
```

If you wanted the first 5 rows and the first 2 columns, you could do either of these:

```
# good
dd[1:5, 1:2]                # using column indices
dd[1:5, c("col1", "col2")]  # using column names
```

But what you have in  your question is

```
# bad
dd[1:5, c(dd$col1, dd$col2)] # using actual values :(
```

What columns are you asking for? Well, `dd$col1` is the first column values: 1,2,1,2,... and `dd$col2` is the second column values 1,2,3,1,2,3... Using `c()` you are sticking them together, so we can expand this out to

```
c(dd$col1, dd$col2) # these are the columns you are asking for
# [1] 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1

# these are equivalent for this data
dd[1:5, c(dd$col1, dd$col2)]
dd[1:5, c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1)]
#   col1 col2 col1.1 col2.1 col1.2 col2.2 col1.3 col2.3 col1.4 col2.4 col1.5 col2.5 col3 col1.6 col2.6 col3.1 col1.7 col2.7
# 1    1    1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1    a      1      1      a      1      1
# 2    2    2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2    a      2      2      a      2      2
# 3    1    3      1      3      1      3      1      3      1      3      1      3    a      1      3      a      1      3
# 4    2    1      2      1      2      1      2      1      2      1      2      1    a      2      1      a      2      1
# 5    1    2      1      2      1      2      1      2      1      2      1      2    a      1      2      a      1      2
#   col3.2 col1.8
# 1      a      1
# 2      a      2
# 3      a      1
# 4      a      2
# 5      a      1
```

We are asking to repeat the columns again and again, with twice as many columns as there are rows in the original data! I don't know how many rows you have, it looks like more than 1000, so you are asking not for 2 columns, but for more than 2000 columns - maybe a lot more.

---

Two footnotes:

1. I second the the comment recommending `data.table::fwrite`, it will be much faster.
2. As a debugging technique, don't forget you can run small pieces of code to isolate the problem. When you try

   ```
   write.table(data_2[1:1000,c(data_2$va_closer_detail,data_2$va_closer_id)], 
       file = "/Volumes/2018/06_abteilungen/bi/analytics/tools/adobe/adobe_analytics/adobe_analytics_api_rohdaten/api_via_data_feed_auf_ftp/beispiel_datenexporte_data_feed/r_exporte/channel_va_closer.csv",
       sep = ";", col.names = NA)
   ```

And it doesn't seem to work there are two things worth checking: (a) is the file path valid, (b) is the data valid. If you had just tried running the `data_2[...]` part of the line, you would have identified the problem without needing help.

```
data_2[1:1000,c(data_2$va_closer_detail,data_2$va_closer_id)]
```

And when you ran that and saw different output than expected, again you run a smaller piece of the line,

```
c(data_2$va_closer_detail,data_2$va_closer_id)
```

And hopefully the issue is clear.